# Can mobs spawn on carpets?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I want to mob-proof the main island in the End and I'd like to use carpets for it, as they are cheap (for me, I have a massive sheep farm) and also look nicer in my eyes than most slabs. Can Endermen spawn on carpets?

Answer (score 2):

**Nope!**
As of [patch 1.8](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Java_Edition_14w29a),

> Carpets now have a hitbox height of 1⁄16 of a block instead of 0. As a result of this, mobs can no longer spawn on carpet.