# Can players spawn on carpets in Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-bedrock-edition

I'm planning a spawn area for my world and I want to use carpets for the floor, but can players spawn on carpets?

[image: Minecraft Carpets]

A [similar question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/353570/can-mobs-spawn-on-carpets) was asked for mobs spawning on carpets, but what about players? Can players spawn on carpets?

Comment: Please specify which game you actually mean. Also, please stop spamming nearly identical questions.

Comment: @FabianRöling I did. I added tags for the versions of the games I want it for. I added the tags for Bedrock and Java Edition. I didn't feel like it is needed to specify in the question since that is what the tags are for.

Comment: @FabianRöling And for the second sentence. Why? Like you said: "nearly". These questions aren't identical. They are different questions and I would like answers for them. Therefore I ask the questions. That's the point of this website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Yes**. You can spawn on carpets.

I found an old world of mine where I have my spawn area covered in carpets. I killed myself and I immediately spawned on my carpets.

Here's a screenshot showing me spawning on the carpets:

[image: Minecraft Bedrock Edition]

This was taken in Bedrock Edition, but I'm 99.99% sure that it is the same in Java Edition also.